# How can you make the radio button auto select 'Yes' based on a value from the previous web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On the first page of the webpage, it asks the user to select the type of product they want from a drop down list and each product is given a value of either 0,1,2... 
Then once they continue they are sent to a different web page and over there based on the product they choose I want the radio button to automatically be selected Yes or No.

If they choose product with value of 2 or 6 then the radio button should be checked to 'Yes' otherwise it should remain blank

Comment: Are you using some kind of backend (such as PHP) on your website ?

Comment: How does the 0-6 value from the previous page get to the new page?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag in query string or cookies and make use of it in the next webpage.

Comment: ..or localstorage (just wanted to add that)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LocalStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store the item value on page1 and request it at page2. Here is an example (won't work here, cause of security resons of the snippet-window):

```js
//page 1
localStorage.setItem("some-name-you-prefer", "value-to-deliver");

var value = 2;
localStorage.setItem("value", value);
console.log(value);

//page2 
localStorage.getItem("some-name-you-prefer");

var value = localStorage.getItem("value");
console.log(value);
```

Be careful, cause the localStorage only stores strings. You can easily store objects with `JSON.stringify(obj);` and `JSON.parse(localStorageItem);`.